# How do multiple death triggers work with a board wipe?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, question, I have a hooded Hydra face up and a Vastwood Hydra out. They both have 4 (+1+1) counters on them. Someone goes to boardwipe, since they both have death triggers can I then move the counters off of Vastwood and turn Hooded Hydra into an 8/8, then get the 8 snake tokens? Or could I wait for both of them to die, get the 4 snake tokens and then distribute the counters from Vastwood any way I like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both [Vastwood Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVastwood%20Hydra%5d) and [Hooded Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHooded%20Hydra%5d) have **leave the battlefield** triggers. As their name implies, they will trigger only when the creatures actually leave the battlefield.

What that implies is that you cannot move the +1/+1 counters off Vastwood Hydra and into Hooded Hydra because (assuming, by your question, that they will both die at the same time), none of the hydras will be on the battlefield by the time Vastwood Hydra's trigger resolves.

You **can**, however, put the triggers into the stack in any order you want. That means that you may put Hooded Hydra's trigger on top of Vastwood Hydra's, get your snake tokens when it resolves, and then resolve the trigger that puts the counters onto those tokens, so the answer to the second part of your question is yes, as long as you stack the triggers properly.